# global instance of class vs namespace

Tags: c++

I've been wondering if there was a clear design pattern when dealing with the following situation:

I have some data that is closely related to each other and I want some functions that modify and give behavior to this data. This seems like the perfect situation to use a class however I only need a single instance of the class.

Would it be better to keep the class and have a global instance or to store the variables in a namespace with the functions?

I'm currently doing the namespace approach when I encounter these situations however I don't like the loss of encapsulation yet I also don't like using global variables. I feel like there should already exist a well thought out solution that I've just never heard of before. Anyone can help on the matter?

**class** example:

```
class someclass {
public:
    double somedouble = 0.0;
    int someint = 0;

    void somefunc() {
        // do some stuff with the variables
        somedouble = someint * 2;
        ++someint;
    }
} someinstance;
```

**vs**

**namespace** example:

```
namespace mynamespace {
    double somedouble = 0.0;
    int someint = 0;

    void somefunc() {
        // do some stuff with the variables
        somedouble = someint * 2;
        ++someint;
    }
} // namespace mynamespace
```

Comment: That sounds like a [singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008019/c-singleton-design-pattern).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference between the use cases of class and namespace.

The answer to your question is that **you should keep a class and have a global instance.**

It can be done using namespace as well but that is not a recommended approach because that’s what we have classes for.

**Namespaces** are used to organize code into logical groups and to prevent name collisions that can occur especially when your codebase includes multiple libraries.

**Using namespaces in such cases (you have mentioned above) is strictly not recommended.**

Answer (score 0):

IMHO you're thinking incorrectly two things has nothing to do each other, a class/struct and a name space or scope purposes

**class or struct** purpose is for encapsulating any functional system in form of structured / organized data
so you can use, manipulate, reuse, and grow it easily well

**namespace**  purpose is to ensure the variable/function names are only used correctly on the targets intended wherever the requiring instances resides and will not otherwise used by other than them